# unable to get EF5.0 codefirst migration to make inital DB

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, entity-framework-5

I am writting my first web application and am trying to learn EF 5.0 code first. I have spent the last two days on google and MSDN trying to figure out how to make this stuff work but none of it is treally geared to first time learners. So can someone please help me using code example with what I am doing wrong? When I run my app in debug no DB is created, when I try to configure migrations from VS2012's package manager I get an error saying "an error occurred while getting the provider information from the database." The blow is my "table".cs file, Context.cs and web.config. From what I can see from all the stuff I have read I am not missing anything.

table.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace FFCollection.DAL
{
    public class Item
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Int16 ItemID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Item Name is required.")]
        [Column("ItemName")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Int16 RegionID { get; set; }
        public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Context.cs:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace FFCollection.DAL
{
    public class FullContext : DbContext
    {
        public FullContext() : base("FFCollection") { }

        public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

web.confg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CollectionDB"
          connectionString="Data Source=192.198.0.2; Initial Catalog=FFColection; User ID=; Password=!" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />

    <customErrors mode="Off" />

    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I know this place is supposed to be only for really experianced people that have years of experiance to ask questions but no where I turn is helping and I am lost so please I just really need some help on where to jump. If someon can help me figure out why the DB is not being made I can continue on with my experimtation of code first EF 5.0

Comment: Can you try adding the following to your connection string entry `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` so that it looks like this `<add name="CollectionDB" connectionString="Data Source=192.198.0.2; Initial Catalog=FFColection; User ID=; Password=!" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`? Btw. I don't think stackoverflow is only for experienced people...

Comment: @Pawel
Adding that gives me the error:

"An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct."

How but I only have one connection string so shouldn't EF default to that one or do I have to declare it somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was write the problem is that EF does not create the database until the first attempt to access it. So I had to add a bit of code in my index.aspx page to try to add an item to the DB. This caused it to create the database

Comment: Or `context.Database.Create()` :)

Comment: I ran across that when I was looking up a simple way to query the DB but was not sure where to put it (was thinking Global.asax but could not figure out exactly what was needed since Database was not an option of context in a default Global.asax page)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<add name="FFColection"
      connectionString="Data Source=192.198.0.2;
                        Initial Catalog=FFColection;
                        User ID=; Password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" 
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

The constructor `base("FFCollection")` either takes the string argument as a full connection string or the name of a connection string in the config file. So it should be "FFColection" in the constructor and the name.

Maybe the address of the server is not enough. You may have to append the name of the sql server instance, like `192.198.0.2\sql2008` (check with Sql Server management studio on the data base machine).

Comment: I noticed the misspelling error and corrected that. That fixed the error message but still no DB is getting generated. I have never had to specify instance names and just to test I gave the IP of my production server which works in an existing Web Site with no instance name but, still, no database is being made.